# Installling Ubuntu on older computer that does not seem to recognise cd drive

Tags: boot, windows, cd-drive

I want to install Ubuntu on an older pc that is running Windows 98. I burned a cd download, but when I put it into the cd drive nothing happens (the disc is recognized as Ubuntu in Windows 8). I've tried changing the BIOS boot order and it will not boot. When I try to access the cd drive through windows it says "E: is not accessible, Device is not ready". The drive shows up in My Computer, but there are no system properties data. Through DOS, the system says it is an invalid drive. However, an old commercial video game (helicopter flight sim) does run properly through the cd, and it will play music cd's .

There are also USB ports (4). A memory stick plugged into one is not recognized as a valid drive (I tried installing that way first). However, on a screen that appears briefly before windows starts the memory stick is recognized and named (Kingston G3).

It has an Ethernet connection, but when I connect it and try to go online (internet explorer) it goes to modem installation wizard and the system cannot find one.

It has a floppy drive that works, and I have tried using 'rawrite -f sbm.bin(rawwritewin.exe sbm.bin)' to make a boot disc, but I can't get it to run in either windows or dos. I tried various combinations of that command, with spaces, without, and nothing (I did manage to format a disc properly using the 'run' command). The computer I *can* download Ubuntu from does not have a floppy drive.

Anyone got any suggestions about what is going on? My computer/programming knowledge is only basic.

Comment: When you burned the CD, what burn speed did you use??  If possible use no more than 4x and redo the burning...

Comment: Can you try booting a newer PC off this CD, and if so, does it work - ie is it a good disk? You did use a 32-bit Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

Did you burn your installation CD using Windows 98?

If Windows 8 computer detects your cd-rom as Ubuntu installation CD then the problem is not the cd-rom media but BIOS settings of your Windows 98 computer.
Try to find a bootable CD-ROM disk (maybe Windows 98 rescue CD?) just to verify that your BIOS settings are correct to boot from CD-ROM.

General issues:
1. Eject CD right after burning it (wait until burning is totally finished) and put CD back just to test if Windows 98 can read this CD correctly
2. Did you create a bootable iso CD? This is a common mistake at least for me when I burned my first installation CD's
3. Did you calculate checksum's for downloaded iso before burning it to CD? 
One option is to download iso-file again and save it different name (or rename older version before downloading) and compare that two files are equal. If they are not use newer version.
4. Some older CD-ROM devices don't read for example CD-RW media correctly. Then you have to burn your CD using CD-R media. Check that you have burned your CD using media that is readable in your old computer.